# iPhone 5 Media Queries overriting iPhone4 + Other Hierarchy Issues

Tags: css, iphone, mobile, media-queries, iphone-4

So, this is how I've set up my media queries thus far.

```
/* iPhone 4 -------------------------- */

@media only screen
and (min-device-width : 320px)
and (max-device-height : 480px)
and (orientation : portrait){
    /* Styles */
}

@media only screen
and (min-device-width : 320px)
and (max-device-height : 480px)
and (orientation: landscape){
    /* Styles */
}

/* iPhone 5 -------------------------- */

@media only screen
and (min-device-width : 320px)
and (max-device-width : 568px)
and (orientation : portrait){
    /* Styles */
}

@media only screen
and (min-device-width : 320px)
and (max-device-width : 568px)
and (orientation : landscape){
    /* Styles */
};

/* iPhone 6 -------------------------- */

@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 375px) 
and (max-device-width : 667px) 
and (orientation : landscape) 
and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio : 2)
{ }

@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 375px) 
and (max-device-width : 667px) 
and (orientation : portrait) 
and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio : 2){ 
    /* Styles */
}

/* Smartphones (portrait) ----------- */

/* Smartphones (landscape) ----------- */


/* iPads (portrait) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : portrait) {
    /* Styles */
}

/* iPads (landscape) ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-device-width : 768px) 
and (max-device-width : 1024px) 
and (orientation : landscape) {
    /* Styles */
}

/* Desktops and laptops ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-width : 1280px) {
    /* Styles */
}

/* Large screens ----------- */
@media only screen 
and (min-width : 1824px) {
    /* Styles */
}
```

My issue is I can't get the hierarchy of these queries to load in the order I have them in. One overwrites the other in typically illogical manners. What am I not understanding here?

Comment: I think you could try to make it simpler, try applying Mobile First theories so  you start from the smallest to the biggest, and focus on max-widths.

Comment: From what I'm seeing, I'm already doing all of that.

Comment: Do you really need to set max and min width of all of these devices? Most of the time I can do just fine by just having, for example: `max-width: 480px`, then goes `min-width: 600px` and so on. That way you wouldn't really need to have aaaaall the mediaqueries there are, unless it's for specific fixes, of course.

Comment: It's all specific positioning issues. I'm simply working down the list of devices I can test via chrome dev tools. But what you're suggesting is to stagger the max-width / min-width series instead of making case specific media queries?

Comment: I don't know details of what you're working on, but I think it'll make it easier to maintain and to fix problems, in case there are, if you make more general media queries and if you order your styles from smallest to biggest.